# how to save json model object to php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, gojs

this is my first post so if im missing anything please be patient :).

im using the go-debug.js library from [GoJS](http://gojs.net/latest/index.html) to make some diagrams on the browser but im running an issue with the saving option. This diagram produce a JavaScript object which you can converted to Json and pass it to the Database by this command **myDiagram.model.toJson()** . I want when i press the save button to save the diagram using the **Ajax** method to **PhP** and then into **mySQL** database.

Thank you for your help!

here is my save script but i can't figure out why it doesnt work.

```
  window.onload = function(){


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'savemodel.php',
    data: {json: JSON.stringify(modelJson)},
    dataType: 'json'
})

.done( function( data ) {
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data);
})
.fail( function( data ) {
    console.log('fail');
    console.log(data);
})
});

    //return modelJson;



  }
  function load() {
    myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
    // loadDiagramProperties gets called later, upon the "InitialLayoutCompleted" DiagramEvent
  }


  function loadDiagramProperties(e) {
    var pos = myDiagram.model.modelData.position;
    if (pos) myDiagram.position = go.Point.parse(pos);
  }



  }
```

and my php code is:

```
      <?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
include 'config.php';
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$session_id=$_SESSION['sess_user_id']; // User session id

$modelJson = $_POST['json'];




$sql = "INSERT INTO c_map 
       (ref_num, members_id, title, description, ingredients) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$session_id', 'title', 'description',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($modelJson)."');";


mysqli_query($connection, $sql);





?>
```

eg. The produce of the command myDiagram.model.toJson(); which is  a tree diagram with 2 children will look like this:

```
{ "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
  "modelData": {"position":"-545.114064532096 -44.69966023522102"},
  "nodeDataArray": [ 
{"key":"Alpha"},
{"key":"N"},
{"key":"N2"}
 ],
  "linkDataArray": [ 
{"from":"Alpha", "to":"N"},
{"from":"Alpha", "to":"N2"}
 ]}
```

I quote the model save documentation from the GoJs site:

> GoJS does not require you to save models in any particular medium or
>   format. But because this is JavaScript and JSON is the most popular
>   data-interchange format, we do make it easy to write and read models
>   as text in JSON format.
>
> Just call Model.toJson to generate a string representing your model.
>   Call the static method Model.fromJson to construct and initialize a
>   model given a string produced by Model.toJson. Many of the samples
>   demonstrate this -- search for JavaScript functions named "save" and
>   "load". Most of those functions write and read a TextArea on the page
>   itself, so that you can see and modify the JSON text and then load it
>   to get a new diagram. But please be cautious when editing because JSON
>   syntax is very strict, and any syntax errors will cause those "load"
>   functions to fail.
>
> JSON formatted text has strict limits on the kinds of data that you
>   can represent without additional assumptions. To save and load any
>   data properties that you set on your node data (or link data), they
>   need to meet the following requirements:
>
> the property is enumerable and its name does not start with an
>   underscore (you can use property names that do start with an
>   underscore, but they won't be saved) the property value is not
>   undefined and is not a function (JSON cannot faithfully hold
>   functions) the model knows how to convert the property value to JSON
>   format (numbers, strings, JavaScript Arrays, or plain JavaScript
>   Objects) property values that are Objects or Arrays form a tree
>   structure -- no shared or cyclical references Model.toJson and
>   Model.fromJson will also handle instances of Point, Size, Rect, Spot,
>   Margin, Geometry, and non-pattern Brushes. However we recommend that
>   you store those objects in their string representations, using those
>   classes' parse and stringify static functions.
>
> Because you are using JavaScript, it is trivial for you to add data
>   properties to your node data. This allows you to associate whatever
>   information you need with each node. But if you need to associate some
>   information with the model, which will be present even if there is no
>   node data at all, you can add properties to the Model.modelData
>   object. This object's properties will be written by Model.toJson and
>   read by Model.fromJson, just as node data objects are written and
>   read.

Comment: It looks like you are simply stingifying the literal value `"modelJson"` whereas I presume you wanted to stringify the value of the model from your app?

Comment: I dont know if its need to stingify this and if it does, to pass it to the php

Comment: If you have additional details to add to your question please use the `edit` link under your question, comments are not a good format for adding additional code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `json_decode` this JSON, because it's becoming an Object.
Remove this part:

```
$directions = json_decode($_POST['json']);
var_dump(directions); // here's an error btw
```

And change it to this:

```
$directions = $_POST['json'];
```

Then just save it in text mode.
Don't forget to escape it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO c_map 
       (ref_num, members_id, title, description, ingredients) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$session_id', 'title', 'description',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($directions)."');";
```

Comment: ok but how php knows that this $directions = $_POST['json']; comes from the ajax post?

Comment: what do you mean? It doesn't. If security is a concern, you may have to add some more variables, etc. This is a different topic, I suppose

Comment: well, i've changed it but it still doesnt work. How can i see the errors of that? 

This is the new php code:
`$modelJson = $_POST['json'];

$modelJson=$str_json;
 //$ingred=$_POST['modelJson'];
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO c_map 
       (ref_num, members_id, title, description, ingredients) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$session_id', 'title', 'description',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($modelJson)."');";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
`

Comment: well, you make no sense. Look what you did: `$modelJson = $_POST['json']; $modelJson=$str_json; `. The variable gets overwritten

Comment: oups, right.. i've deleted the ` $modelJson=$str_json; ` command but still nothing shows in the db. Can i see the errors of the PhP in some way?
I mean, how can i be sure that my php code logic works... :/  The  below commands doesn't work either 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Check the webserver logs for the error messages. They're always there, even if suppressed in browser. Please select the answer, if it helped

Comment: im not sure what the problem is... my debug console says `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionmain-js.js:185 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:16 f.resolveWithjquery.min.js:16 f.donejquery.min.js:16 d.fn.d.readymain-js.js:184 save `

Also i've quoted the documentation of the GoJs library in the description.

Comment: If you can't give a link, at least make a screenshot of the code and paste here

Comment: ok i solve it. The problem was a conflict with the $ variable . i used Jquery instead of $. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me when I save a JSON string transferred from an input (hidden) tag using a post method in a form.

```
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];  // Get the data
// open connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");  
// Convert all characters to the correct saving string
// Important! the connection should be open!
$mdata = **mysqli_real_escape_string**($conn, $data);
// The SQL query requires a '...' when using a string
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (info) VALUES ('$data')";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

This process will add some characters to your stored field.
The good thing is when you read it (using select) all will be great with no need to do anything.

Good luck